# Group By year in LINQ

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I'm trying to show a list of elements grouped by the year. 
This is what I have done in the controller:

```
public ActionResult YearNewsList()
{
   var YearsList = db.tble_news.GroupBy(x => x.content_show_date.Value.Year)
                               .Distinct();
   return PartialView(YearsList);
}
```

And this is what I have done on the view

```
@model IEnumerable<invensys.Models.tble_news>     

@foreach (var item in Model) {        
   @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.content_show_date.Value.Year)              
}
```

But I always get the following when I try to run this:

> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type
>   'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1[System.Linq.IGrouping`2[System.Int32,invensys.Models.tble_news]]',
>   but this dictionary requires a model item of type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[invensys.Models.tble_news]'.

Comment: What type is 'var YearList'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`GroupBy` returns `IEnumerable<IGrouping<TKey, TSource>>` object which you try to make it `IEnumerable<TSource>`.

In your case,you should define model of the view

`@model IEnumerable<IGrouping<int, invensys.Models.tble_news>>`

if your `x.content_show_date.Value.Year` type is int.

Then you can display the infos like this:

```
        @foreach (var groupItem in model)
        {
            @Html.DisplayFor(groupItem.Key)
            //some code to display groupitems by loop groupItem
        }
```

Comment: Thanks everyone, but Jarvan your method did the trick many thanks
Hesh

Answer (score 0):

.Distinct() will return disctint **Groupings** (all Groupings).
If you want year to be represented by any invensys.Models.tble_news, instead of .Distinct() use

```
.Select(grouping => grouping.First())
```